# Non-zero potential on an equipotential surface

Tags: electrostatics, potential, potential-energy

I read that an equipotential surface can intersect itself and at the intersection point, the electric field must be zero, and the potential is the same as on the surface but my doubt is how the potential is non-zero there without an electric field. I am a high school student.

Answer (score 1):

No intersection can exist between equipotential surfaces, if the potential on them has different values.

On an equipotential surface, the value of the potential $V$ is constant.

Let's consider two equipotential surfaces $S_1$ where $V = V_1$ and $S_2$ where $V = V_2 \ne V_1$, and let's assume that an intersection exists. What would the value of the potential be in these points? $V_1$? $V_2$? Both? So they can't have intersections.

If two equipotential surfaces have the same value of potential, $V_2 = V_1$, they can intersect. But why would you consider these two as different surfaces here and not the same surface?

Have a look at the answers to this question, [Intersection of equipotential surfaces](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/657705/intersection-of-equipotential-surfaces).

Answer (score 1):

There's an analogy that can help with this.  Think of the electric potential as the *elevation* of the ground at a particular location;  if the potential is zero at a particular point, this corresponds to being at "sea level".  The electric field is the *slope* of the ground at a particular point.  Steeper terrain corresponds to a larger electric field;  and if the electric field is zero at a particular point, this corresponds to $\vec{E} = 0$ at that point.

You ask, "how can the electric field be zero at a particular point where the potential is not zero?"  In this analogy, this is like asking, "how can the ground be level at a point that's not at sea level?"  The answer is that if you're at the peak of a hill, or the bottom of a valley, or at a [saddle point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saddle_(landform)), then the ground can be level where you are even if you're not at "sea level".